# How to do multiline python code in .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

So going with this short example:

```
GridLayout:
    id: matrixA
    cols: 1
    Button:
        on_press:
            for i in range(root.matrixArows):\
            for j in range(root.matrixAcols):\
            print(i)
```

I want to make nested for loop in my kivy file, however it keeps returning the error.[image]

The root.matrixArows and cols exists and is being read propely for sure, I don't know if I am making something wrong with the syntax on multiline code.

Comment: The code containing just the loop over "i" works, if there are two loops it doesn't work

Comment: I think that is not possible at this moment since kvlang parser is not designed to parse at deep level. Moreover kvlang is intended to be used to describe the UI mainly. So you can implement the necessary logic in python.

Comment: I was trying to make a matrix where you can input matrix size and later on the posted matrix size would appear as TextInput to fill. I wanted to make I'd to them, but seems like I will need to find another way.